# The name 'TextboxUN' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net

The name `TextboxUN` does not exist in the current context

I'm new to this stuff and I don't really know what the problem is, I've tried every possible way to fix this but I can't seem to fix it.

```
 string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where Username='" + TextboxUN.Text + "'";

<asp:TextBox ID="TextboxUN" runat="server" Width="140px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
```

Comment: You have forgotten to show your aspx code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to declare the variables that you are using first before processing your program

please explain your question well and give more details

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that **TextboxUN** exists in both **xxx.aspx** and **xxx.aspx.designer.cs**

In addition, use **Parameterized Query** to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

[image]

[image]

Comment: i've checked it a bunch a times ive posted the the code above for my
.aspx

they're both the same

Comment: Did you see **TextboxUN** in **xxx.aspx.designer.cs**? If you do not see it, please post everything inside your ASPX page; most likely it is nested inside other server control.